# OpenGL: Copying a Frame Buffer Object

Tags: opengl, opengl-es

I need to gather information about the target used in a texture attachment of an `FBO` in order to copy it to another `FBO`.

As far as `OpenGL ES 2.0` is concerned, I can use `glGetFramebufferAttachmentParameter[if]v()` and, since `OpenGL ES 2.0` only supports `GL_TEXTURE_2D` and `GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP`, the information returned is enough to determine the texture target that was used (when it's not a cube map face, it is a `GL_TEXTURE_2D` since it can't be anything else).

On the desktop, however, things change:

Because then we have `GL_TEXTURE_1D`, `GL_TEXTURE_2D`, `GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE`, `GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE`, `GL_TEXTURE_3D`, and the 6 cube map faces as valid targets for an `FBO's` texture attachment, and while the 6 cube map faces and `GL_TEXTURE_3D` targets are easy to tell (since there are specific queries for cube map faces and layered textures), the same does not apply to the remaining targets: `GL_TEXTURE_1D`, `GL_TEXTURE_2D`, `GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE`, and `GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE`, at least as far as the manual pages are concerned.  Therefore, how would I be able to tell which of these 4 targets was used in a texture attachment?

The need to copy an `FBO` stems from the fact that `FBOs` are not shared between contexts, the implementation creates screen `FBOs` in the main thread, and I want to use them in child threads dedicated to each screen so as to not stall the main thread with render loops and thus keep the application responsive to UI events.  Caching state is both undesirable and unfeasible in this case; undesirable because it cuts through otherwise distinct concerns of the application when the client library (which only concern is to serve as a communication API between the application and the `OpenGL` server) is in a much better position to cache state itself, and unfeasible since in this case I don't even control some of the concerns in my application, as mentioned before.

Right now this is a theoretical question, because the implementation I'm working on only supports OpenGL ES 2.0, but I would rather write future-proof code where I can be certain about the exact texture target used as an FBO attachment than code that works only because the number of available options is limited to the point where I can figure out which option was chosen by excluding those that weren't, an approach that, as demonstrated above, wouldn't work on the feature-rich desktop versions and may not work on future OpenGL ES version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenGL has no solution for the problem you're having. There is no way to look at a texture object and know what target it is, nor is there a way to know what the `textarget` parameter of a texture that was attached to an FBO was. Generally speaking, you are expected to keep track of the texture object's target, just as you're expected to keep track of the texture object's *name* (the `GLuint` you get back from `glGenTextures`).

The best way to handle this would be to simply ask the client library what textures and texture targets it adds to it's FBO. If you can't get this client library to provide you this information, then you can't do what you need to do.

Comment: I have come up with a way to abstract this neatly: since I need composition for several effects and composition is essentially weightless to the CPU, I can do that step in the main thread for screen FBOs thus avoiding the need to copy them; then all cameras will be rendering to off-screen FBOs that they have absolute control over.